# Phonegap - Load a specific part of an app based on an external link

Tags: cordova

I have seen native apps do this and wonder if it's possible using PhoneGap:

App A presents an action to the user and when clicked loads App B to a certain section.

Usecase:
Siri provides an address to a restaurant and when clicked opens Maps up to that address ready to give directions.

Question is, using PhoneGap can App A open App B and not just open it but open it to a specific section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at URL Schemes. Basically you make sure your application URL and custom Query-strings and when phonegap loads it listens to the incoming url and passes it on to Javascript to be used.

For example I can load up the native twitter app on my iphone by using

```
twitter:///user?screen_name=myusername
```

So you can register `myFabApp://object1=blah&object2=blah`

Here is more information about using it in Phonegap Javascript 
https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Custom%20URL%20Scheme%20Handling.md

Then once you have the values in your app you can do what ever actions you like .

If this helped please up-vote :-)

Comment: that is perfect! Does such a solution exist on the Android platform as well? We would need to implement both.

Comment: Looks like you can.
http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/launching-an-android-application-from-a-url/

Comment: broken link my friend @AdamWare